# How to mark/import subfolders as Maven projects in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have imported a project from git, where topmost folder does not contain any pom file. It has src folder and some java files under it's tree.

Simultaneously, it has several subfolders with pom files in each.

How to force IntelliJ think these are projects?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> How to force IntelliJ think these are projects?

You can add them as modules to your IDEA project. Open the Maven tool window  and use the add button [image] to add them.

If you want each to be a separate IDEA project, then simply use *File > Project from Existing Sources* for each one and select the pom file.

[image]

Comment: How to open the maven tool window?

Comment: If you don't have the Maven tool window, here are a couple of options. 1. Find the action "Add Maven Projects" from Navigate/"Search Everywhere". 2. File/New/"Module from Existing Sources".

Answer (score 3):

You can also think about creating a "super pom" file in the root, which has a `<modules>` section which specifies the sub folder of each of the various modules, containing their own pom.xml files.

The packaging of the super pom should be `pom`.

If the sub module pom.xml files are configured with a `parent` to the super pom, you can centralise configuration properties in one place, as well as being able to build all the modules by simply building the parent pom.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually by adding a "misc.xml" to your ".idea" directory
That contains your maven subdirectory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ExternalStorageConfigurationManager" enabled="true" />
  <component name="MavenProjectsManager">
    <option name="originalFiles">
      <list>
        <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/YourSubDirectoryName/pom.xml" />
      </list>
    </option>
  </component>
  <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_17" default="true" project-jdk-name="17" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK" />
</project>
```

Then you need to restart your IDE to load new configurations

That's work for me with the last **Intellij version 2022.3.1**